# Match words that start with specified text

Tags: regex

I want to match to strings that begin with words "function" or"action"

```
somethingelse.Exit
function.Click
checkbox.Click
function.dontwantthis.Click checkbox.Click
javascript.Click function.Click
```

I want to match to these strings in the example input

```
function.Click
checkbox.Click
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: `^(function|checkbox).Click`

Comment: That's almost what I want, but can I do the opposite that I exclude certain strings. I  edited my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this regex:

```
(?!(Javascript|action))^.*.Click$
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/Lqqsfv/1)

Answer (score 0):

if you want only 2 of them, so use this :

> (function|checkbox)\.Click

Tips : you can use an online reg ex  for example : https://www.regextester.com/